# How can I split my koa routes into separate files?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

I'm trying to figure out how to split my routes into separate files.

I have this so far, but it doesn't work. I just get `Not found` when I try to access `http://localhost:3001/api/things`

```
//server.js
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();
var router = require('koa-router');

app.use(router(app));
require('./routes')(app);


// routes.js
module.exports = function *(app){
  app.use('/api/things', require('./api/things'));
};


// api/things/index.js

var Router = require('koa-router');
var router = new Router({
  prefix: '/api/things'
});

router.get('/', function *(){
  this.body = [{ name: 'Foo'}, { name: 'Bar' }];
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi if you're still active can you change the accepted answer? To the one with 47 votes.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

---

**EDIT**: I've updated the code examples below because the `koa-router` package on npm is no longer maintained. The Koa team has made an official fork of it under the name `@koa/router`.

---

For anyone reading this, who is curious on how to do this in Koa 2.X:

**app.js**

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import rootRouter from './routes/root'
import userRouter from './routes/user'

const app = new Koa()

app.use(rootRouter.routes())
app.use(rootRouter.allowedMethods())
app.use(userRouter.routes())
app.use(userRouter.allowedMethods())

export default app
```

**routes/root.js**

```
import Router from '@koa/router'
const router = new Router()

router.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello'
})

export default router
```

**routes/user.js**

```
import Router from '@koa/router'
const router = new Router({ prefix: '/user' })

router.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Some User'
})

export default router
```

If you want to avoid the repetition with the `routes()` and the `allowedMethods()`, you can use `koa-compose` to compose the middleware together. For simplicity, I made a [wrapper](https://github.com/saadq/koa-combine-routers/) around it to simplify working with `koa-router`. Using it would look something like this:

**app.js**

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import router from './routes'

const app = new Koa()

app.use(router())

export default app
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import combineRouters from 'koa-combine-routers'
import rootRouter from './root'
import userRouter from './user'

const router = combineRouters(
  rootRouter,
  userRouter
)

export default router
```

And it would do the same thing.

Comment: I have tried this solution but I have the next error: Router is not defined.

Comment: @nole. do you have a code sample you can share with something like [GitHub gist](http://gist.github.com)?

Answer (score 19):

#### server.js

```
var app = require('koa')();
var router = require('./routes');
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000);
```

#### routes.js

```
var router = require('koa-router')();
router.get('/', function* () {
    this.body = 'router test';
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 12):

Something like this should work:

```
// app.js
var koa = require('koa'),
    app = koa();

require('./routes1')(app);
require('./routes2')(app);

app.listen(3000);

// routes1.js
var Router = require('koa-router');
function register (app) {
  var router = new Router({
    prefix: '/api'
  });
  router.get('/', ...); // responds to "/api"
  router.get('/messages', ...); // responds to "/api/messages"
  app.use(router.routes());
  app.use(router.allowedMethods());
}

module.exports = register

// routes2.js
var Router = require('koa-router');
function register (app) {
  var router = new Router();
  router.get('/', ...); // responds to "/"
  app.use(router.routes());
  app.use(router.allowedMethods());
}

module.exports = register
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `allowedMethods()` call?

Comment: Supports http OPTIONS method and responds with something like this:  

200 OK
Allow: HEAD,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS

Essentially specifying the methods the server supports for the given URL

Comment: This is a great solution, but it is now outdated and will not work.

Comment: I forget the details. This is an old post. I believe there was a major update to koa or koa-router that changed the syntax. I ended up needing to do the following: var api = new Router();

var api1 = require('./methods/api1');
api.use('/api1/v0/', api1.routes(), api1.allowedMethods());

var api2 = require('./methods/api2');
api.use('/api2/v0/', api2.routes(), api2.allowedMethods());

app.use(api.routes());

Answer (score 7):

For Koa 2.x I find *nested routes* with *prefixes* to deliver the goods, with no additional packages.

Assuming */api/dogs* and */api/cats* are the required outcomes.

Like so:

**app.js**

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import Router from 'koa-router';
import apiRouter from './routes/apiRouter';

const app = new Koa();

app.use(apiRouter.routes(), apiRouter.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000);

export default app;
```

**routes/apiRouter.js**

```
import Router from 'koa-router'

import dogsRouter from './dogsRouter'
import catsRouter from './catsRouter'

const apiRouter = new Router({ prefix: '/api' })

const nestedRoutes = [dogsRouter, catsRouter]
for (var router of nestedRoutes) {
    apiRouter.use(router.routes(), router.allowedMethods())
}

export default apiRouter;
```

**routes/dogsRouter.js**

```
import Router from 'koa-router'

const dogsRouter = new Router({ prefix: '/dogs' });

dogsRouter.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Dogs be here'
});

export default dogsRouter;
```

**routes/catsRouter.js**

```
import Router from 'koa-router'

const catsRouter = new Router({ prefix: '/cats' });

catsRouter.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'Cats be here'
});

export default catsRouter;
```

Answer (score 4):

Minimalistic approach which i think **TJ** kept in mind when he did

**koa, koa-route, koa-mount**

Approach with small independent apps which mounted the way you like then:

**index.js**

```
var app = require('./app')
app.listen(3000);
```

**app.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const _ = require('koa-route')
const mount = require('koa-mount')
const app = new Koa()
const pets = require('./pets')

// sub apps
app.use(mount('/pets', pets))

// root app
app.use(_.get('/', function(){
  this.body = "hello";
}))

module.exports = app;
```

**pets.js**

```
var Koa = require('koa');
var _ = require('koa-route');
var app = new Koa();


app.use(_.get('/', ctx => ctx.body = "pets" ));
app.use(_.get('/:name', (ctx, name) => ctx.body = "pet: "+ name));

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up going with:

```
//server.js
'use strict';

var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();
var serve = require('koa-static');
var path = require('path');
var router = require('koa-router');
var cfg = require('./config');
var mw = require('./middleware');

app.use(serve(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
app.use(mw.requestTime('Response-time'));
app.use(router(app));
app.use(cfg.db.connect);

require('./routes')(app);

app.get('/api', function *(){
  this.body = 'Welcome to API v1';
});

app.use(cfg.db.close);
app.listen(cfg.env.port);



//routes.js
module.exports = function (app){
  app.use(require('./api/things').routes());
};


// api/things/index.js
var Router = require('koa-router');

var router = new Router({
  prefix: '/api/things'
});

var ctrl = require('./controllers');

router.get('/', ctrl.list);
router.get('/:id', ctrl.get);
router.post('/', ctrl.post);
router.put('/:id', ctrl.put);
router.del('/:id', ctrl.del);

module.exports = router;


// api/things/controllers.js

var r = require('rethinkdb');
var http = require('http');
var parse = require('co-body');
var ctrl = module.exports = {};

ctrl.list = function *(next){
};

ctrl.get = function *(next){
};

ctrl.post = function *(next){
};

ctrl.put = function *(next){
};

ctrl.del = function *(next){
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put all your routes inside a single folder called routes, then loop through all files in that folder, require them and init. That way for any new route, just create a file in routes folder and thats it.

So something like this:

**index.js**

```
const Koa = require("koa");
const logger = require("koa-logger");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");

const app = new Koa();

app.use(logger());
app.use(bodyParser());

require("./routes")(app);

const server = app.listen(config.server.port);

module.exports = server;
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const baseName = path.basename(module.filename);

const routes = fs
    .readdirSync(path.join(__dirname))
    .filter(
        file =>
            file.indexOf(".") !== 0 &&
            file !== baseName &&
            file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    )
    .map(file => require(path.join(__dirname, file)));

module.exports = function(app) {
    for (var router of routes) {
        app.use(router.routes());
    }
};
```

Then inside /routes folder you would have like

/routes/user.js

/routes/customer.js

which are all router exports such as

**/routes/auth.js**

```
const Router = require("koa-router");
const authControllers = require("../controllers/auth");

const {
    jwtAuth,
    login,
    register,
    forgotPassword,
    resetPassword,
    getAuthenticatedUser
} = authControllers;

const router = new Router({ prefix: "/auth" });

router.post("/register", register);
router.post("/login", login);
router.post("/forgot-password", forgotPassword);
router.post("/reset-password/:resetToken", resetPassword);
router.get("/profile", jwtAuth, getAuthenticatedUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer is underrated. This can typically used in large applications to omit redundancy. Simple and follows DRY Principle. Thank you @Goran. Do you mind sharing any other tips for building large Koa apps?

Comment: Hi!
I think your solution is the most valuable and simple solution there is.
Do you know if there are any downsides by using multiple files (thus creating multiple routers with each have his own routes) than using a single router with multiple routes in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

Simular, but exactly what I needed was:

**app.js**

```js
"use strict";
import Koa from 'koa';
const app = new Koa();

import Router from 'koa-router';
const router = new Router();

import mount from 'koa-mount';
import routes from "./router/index.mjs";

app.use(mount(routes));
app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on port: 3000"));
```

**router/index.mjs**

```js
"use strict";
import Koa from 'koa';
const app = new Koa();

import Router from 'koa-router';
const router = new Router();

router.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = {success: true};
    await next();
});

app.use(router.routes());

export default app;
```