# How to combine separated Koa-Routers with Typescript

Tags: typescript, export, koa, koa-router, code-separation

I decided to split my routers by their purpose, so they look like this:

**routers/homeRouter.ts**

```
import * as Router from 'koa-router';

const router: Router = new Router();

router
    .get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
        ctx.body = 'hello world';
    });

export = router;
```

**routers/userRouter.ts**

```
import * as Router from 'koa-router';
import UserController = require('../controller/userController');

const router: Router = new Router(
    {
        prefix: 'users'
    }
);

var userController = new UserController();

router
    .post('/user/:email/:password', userController.signUp);

export = router;
```

With this, my app.ts has to import each of the routers one by one like this:

**app.ts**

```
import * as Koa from 'koa';
import * as homeRouter from './routers/homeRouter';
import * as userRouter from './routers/userRouter';
const app: Koa = new Koa();
app
    .use(homeRouter.routes())
    .use(homeRouter.allowedMethods());
app
    .use(userRouter.routes())
    .use(userRouter.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000);
```

But what I want is this:

**app.ts**

```
import * as Koa from 'koa';
import * as routers from './routers';
const app: Koa = new Koa();
app
    .use(routers.routes())
    .use(routers.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000);
```

I do not know how to export the routers to achieve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: I wrote a utility for this awhile back, I talked about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39301972/4033215) in case you're curious.

Comment: @saadq bit how would you do it with Typescript?

Answer (score 4):

You can have something like this:

**userRouter.ts**

```
import * as Router from 'koa-router';

const router = new Router();
router.get('/', list);

...

export default router.routes();
```

**routes.ts**

```
import * as Router from 'koa-router';


import UserRouter from './userRouter';
import HomeRouter from './homeRouter';

const apiRouter = new Router({ prefix: '/api'});
apiRouter.use('/users', UserRouter);
apiRouter.use('/home', HomeRouter);

export default apiRouter.routes();
```

You can implement each router separately as you have done, then generate a new router which includes all of your routers. Then you can include it in your `app.ts` file.

Answer (score 1):

[Meseret](https://github.com/kaleabmelkie/meseret) is a nice typescript library I wrote that can help you manage your Koa server routers, middleware and much more.

E.g. You can replace your `app.ts` with this.

```
import { ServerApp } from 'meseret'

import HomeRouter from './routers/homeRouter'
import UserRouter from './routers/userRouter'

new ServerApp({
  name: 'Your App Name',
  httpServers: [
    { port: 3000 }
  ],
  routers: [
    HomeRouter,
    UserRouter
  ]
}).start() // returns a Promise
```

All you have to do is just import your `koa-router` Routers and add them to the list of `routers` in the `ServerApp`.

[Meseret](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meseret) helps you do much more than manage routers. It has built in support for Koa sessions, static caching, public directory serving, response compression and more. There's also, as expected, an option that lets you add your own Koa middleware to the app.

Plus, it can connect to [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) and help manage your [Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) models (even by adding static type support to your mongoose models--the paths, methods and statics--if you use the `ModelFactory`).

[Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) web sockets are also supported in the config.

All these features are managed in a single `ServerApp` instance.

Find out more at [meseret's Github page](https://github.com/kaleabmelkie/meseret).

I hope it helps you manage your *distributed* node server project.

Answer (score 1):

[I made a utility](https://github.com/saadq/koa-combine-routers) awhile back for combining multiple instances of `koa-router` into a single middleware, and I just now added a TypeScript definition file, so it should be usable for TS folks. Just `npm install koa-combine-routers` and use it like so:

Usage:

**app.js**

```
import * as Koa from 'koa'
import router from './router'

const app = new Koa()

app.use(router())
```

**routes.js**

```
import * as Router from 'koa-router'
import * as combineRouters from 'koa-combine-routers'

const dogRouter = new Router()
const catRouter = new Router()

dogRouter.get('/dogs', async ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'ok'
})

catRouter.get('/cats', async ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'ok'
})

const router = combineRouters(
  dogRouter, 
  catRouter
)

export default router
```

This will use both `.routes()` and `.allowedMethods()`.